# how to add attributes to custom rails exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling, backend

Say I have a custom error class that inherits from a parent error class. How can I add an attribute to that class, so something like:

```
class CustomError <CustomParentErrorClass
  status: 500
end
```

So that in my controller I could do something like

```
rescue CustomErroClass => e
 head(e.status)
```

I essentially want to access my attribute from my rails error class from my controller but am not sure how to. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define attributes on the `CustomError` class just like any other error class

```
class CustomError < StandardError
  attr_reader :status

  def initialize(status)
    @status = status
  end
end
```

Here is a sample usage

```
begin
  raise CustomError.new(500)
rescue CustomError => e
  head(e.status)
end
```

If the attributes are hard-coded and do not need to be passed from where the error is raised, you can hard-code it

```
class CustomError < StandardError
  attr_reader :status

  def initialize
    @status = 500 # you can also define a constant instead of attribute if the value will be a constant
  end
end
```

That said, a word of caution for the example that you shared:

You are defining a `status` attribute. I am guessing this error will be raised from your model or service class and rescued in the Controller. If this is the case, consider avoiding coupling the model class to the HTTP status that the controller should return.

Comment: I see this seems to work; one question though; Why did you make status an instance variable; why not just `status` instead of `@status`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you asking for the case where `status` will always be `500` (and not passed when raising)? In that case, yeah, you do not need an instance variable. You can just do `def status` that returns `500`

Comment: the instance where the status isnt hardcoded; why do we need instance variables then?

Comment: I see. So, if you do not create an instance variable, and just use `status = ...`, then the variable `status` will be destroyed as soon as we exit the `initialize` method, but we want the `status` to be available even after we exit the `initialize` method; creating an instance variable allows it to exist even after we exist the initialize method. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, can you please accept and upvote, if the answer solved your problem.

Comment: yes that makes sense; thank you, quite new to rails